# reversed range using lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Is there anything similar to python reversed range in [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#range).

In python

```
   list(reversed(range(0, 4)))
=> [3, 2, 1, 0]
   list(reversed(range(3, 4)))
=> [3]
```

in lodash

```
 console.log(_.range(3,4,-1))
[]
   console.log(_.range(0, 4, -1));
[]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the start and stop values reversed.

```
console.log(_.range(3, -1, -1));
# [ 3, 2, 1, 0 ]
```

Alternatively you can use the chainable `reverse` function, with the `range`, like this

```
console.log(_.range(0, 4).reverse());
# [ 3, 2, 1, 0 ]
```

**Note:** Neither of them is similar to Python 3.x's `range` function.

Comment: yup, I knew the start and end reversed, as there is an example in doc with step -1, which works. But, I wanted the python behavior as it still works, even if it can guarantee which is low or high.

Comment: @bsr Then you can use the second method in the answer. But remember, in Python `reversed` will give an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

As of Lodash 4.0.0, there's a [rangeRight](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#rangeRight) method that populates values in descending order.

```
_.rangeRight(1, 5);
// => [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it should be

```
_.range(3,-1,-1)
_.range(3,2,-1)
```

Or with `reverse`:

```
console.log(_.range(3,4).reverse())
console.log(_.range(0,4).reverse())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a reversed list, the first parameter needs to be the higher number. This works:

```
console.log(_.range(4,0,-1); // [4, 3, 2, 1]
```